# web application startup (spring 3.0)

Tags: web-applications, spring-mvc, startup

I want a method (or some functionality) to be executed after my web application starts (context loaded). I am using spring 3.0 as framework.

I tried using ServletContextListener which I implemented in my class

my listener class

```
package myapp.listner;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

public class MyContextListner implements ServletContextListener{

    public static long appStart=0L;
    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {

        System.out.println("Context Destroyed");
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        appStart=System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Context Initialised");

    }

}
```

and part of web.xml is

```
<listner>
     <listner-class>myapp.listner.MyContextListner</listner-class>
    </listner>

    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>

      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/forms/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

but its not printing that message.....

Please help me....

Comment: While I'd lean towards a Spring-oriented solution, are you sure you're looking in the right place? And is the misspelling of "listener" intentional, particularly in `web.xml`? It's best to cut-and-paste examples to avoid red herrings. It works fine for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PostConstruct and PreDestroy annotations, something like this  :

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig{

    @PostConstruct
    public void contextInitialized(){
      System.out.println("Context Initialised");
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void contextdestroyed(){
      System.out.println("Context Destroyed");
    }
}
```

You don't have to use in configuration bean, it can be [anywhere](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-postconstruct-and-predestroy-example/).

Comment: does it need to do entry of lass MyConfig in any xml file..... if not then how MyConfig class is located..?

Comment: No, put it wherever you like as long as it is scanned for annotations - a setting in your app context. Also, it does not have to be in config bean you can put it in any spring managed class.